# Does the use of electronic health records make physicians less efficient at performing their job?

Tags: healthcare

http://time.com/4383979/doctor-burnout-electronic-health-records/ reported on  2016-06-27 that

> nearly 63% of doctors believed that EHRs made their jobs less efficient.

Does the use of electronic health records actually make physicians less efficient at performing their job?

Comment: I've frequently heard similar complaints from physicians. When you move from the physician dictating findings to a nurse or technician who also manages the paperwork to making the physician log in, locate records, review documents and manually type findings, yes, the physician spends a larger percentage of their time working with software. Of course, the physicians' perceptions may not accurately reflect overall efficiency of patient care at an EHR-enabled practice.

Comment: I work with doctors and my impression is that it's about even. Half like them and the other half don't. Of the half that doesn't like them, about half are more Luddite in their approach, having never actually tried one. Physicians tend to be laggards. So the number seems a bit high to me.

Comment: My experiences don't match these other comments. Of the physicians I know that have complained about EHR software, all have tried one, and none are luddites (not half, as fredsbend's experience has been). Also, I don't believe physicians are laggards (contrary to fredsbend's opinion). The number doesn't necessarily seem high. I rarely hear complaints from physicians about EHR system that they use. Hopefully my experience brings more balance to the context these comments are providing to the question.